# Matrix bottom left to top right

Tags: java, algorithm, matrix

Can someone please review this simple code for printing all paths in a matrix from bottom left to top right? If an element is 1, it is a "wall" and you cannot take it.

Possible steps: up and right

```
  // Prints possible paths from bottom left to top right
    public static void findPath(int n, int i , int j, int[][] mat,ArrayList<Integer> path)
    {
        if(i==0 && j==n-1)
        {
            System.out.println();
            for(Integer step: path)
            {
                System.out.print(","+step);
            }
        }

        if(isPossibleStep(i+1,j,n,mat))
        {
            path.add(i+1);
            findPath(n,i+1, j,mat, path);
        }
        else if(isPossibleStep(i,j-1,n,mat))
        {
            path.add(j-1);
            findPath(n,i, j-1,mat, path);
        }

    }

    // Tells if a given path is possible
    public static boolean isPossibleStep(int i, int j, int n,int[][] mat)
    {
        if(mat[i][j]==1)
            return false;

        if(i < n && j > 0)
            return true;
        else
            return false;
    }
```

Also, how do I print just 1 possible path and then exit? It seems like a simple change but I am not able to think of a graceful way of doing it.

Answer (score 1):

You can refactor the `findPath` logic somewhat and reduce the indent level while preserving the method's behavior:

```
// Prints possible paths from bottom left to top right
public static void findPath(int n, int i , int j, int[][] mat, ArrayList<Integer> path)
{
    if(i == 0 && j == n - 1)
    {
        System.out.println();
        for(Integer step: path)
        {
            System.out.print("," + step);
        }
    }

    boolean rightStep = isPossibleStep(i + 1, j, n, mat);                
    if(!isPossibleStep(i, j - 1, n, mat) && !rightStep)
        return;

    path.add(rightStep ? ++i : --j);
    findPath(n, i, j, mat, path);    
}
```

`isPossibleStep` can also be simplified by use of short-circuit logic. The following expresses the intent more directly with the benefit of being terse:

```
public static boolean isPossibleStep(int i, int j, int n, int[][] mat)
{
    return mat[i][j] != 1 
        && i < n 
        && j > 0;
}
```

Comment: Good notes, but the method `isPossibleStep` is still faulty, since the boundaries checks must be done *before* accessing the array. I've suggested a fix in my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I wonder what's the use of adding just `i+1` or `j-1` to the path. Shouldn't the path be composed of index pairs `(i,j)`?

Building upon Victor's answer, here are some more optimizations:

```
public static void findPath(int n, int i, int j, int[][] mat, ArrayList<Integer> path) {
    if (i == 0 && j == n-1) {
        System.out.println(path);    // (1)
    }

    Integer step;    // (2)
    if (isPossibleStep(i + 1, j, n, mat)) {
        step = ++i;
    } else if (isPossibleStep(i, j - 1, n, mat)) {
        step = --j;
    } else {
        return;
    }

    path.add(step);
    findPath(n, i, j, mat, path);
}

public static boolean isPossibleStep(int i, int j, int n, int[][] mat) {
    return i < n && j >= 0    // (3)
        && mat[i][j] != 1;
}
```

Notes:

1. Instead of looping over the collection to print it, `ArrayList`'s `toString()` method can do that (with better performance). If you don't want to print the square brackets, just do a substring:

   ```
   String pathStr = path.toString();
   System.out.println(pathStr.substring(1, pathStr.length()-1);
   ```
2. The code surrounding the temporary `step` variable can be simplified if you use index pairs to represent the path.
3. The method `isPossibleStep` must check the indices *before* it tries to access the matrix. Otherwise you could end up with an `ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException`. Also note that I'm checking for `j >= 0`, because `0` is a valid index. (You should also check that `i >= 0 && j < n` to be safe.)